# Example of the Main Theorem of Complex Multiplication

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

I am trying to understand the main theorem ov CM for elliptic curves. I work with the version stated in the second chapter of Silvermans "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetics of Elliptic Curves". 
I would like to make an example or something what illustrates clearly the statement.

I am looking forward for any ideas!

Comment: You will find lots of material in the links to the right of your question (the **Related** column).

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I read all this stuff. What I am looking for is more a concrete example. I didn't find something therefore. Please correct if i am wrong

Comment: This is not a research-level question, you'd better ask it on Math.SE.